# problems with graphic performance in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, games

in advance: my English is not perfect ;)

processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8500 @ 3.16GHz × 2
memory: 3,9 GiB
graphics: GeForce GTX 460

Ubuntu 12.04 32-Bit fresh installed (previously 11.10 32-Bit)
driver: NVIDIAs accelerated Driver (Version current-updates)

probelm: In Ubuntu 12.04 I have problems with the performance of the graphics (games for example: Volley Brwawl, Neverball, Beep and Minecraft), and effects of windows (always at minimize, maximize...) There are laggs at animations, and the laggs in games are extremely annoying. Problems occur only in Ubuntu 12.04, everything was good in 11.10. No Problems with YouTube videos, HD videos.

Is there a solution? BBecause I have found nothing here in the Forum and on Google. Or is an update coming soonfor driver or whatever? (This Bug is already registered in Launchpad.)

Thank you!

Comment: Just wondering.. Memory is 3GB, 9GB or 3.9GB?

Answer (score 0):

I think the NVIDIA drivers are being updated at the moment - there are all sorts of problems with them and 12.04 (esp for those of us on older graphics cards)... http://slackblogs.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/do-not-use-nvidia-driver-29540.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have already tried this, but if not, open "additional drivers" and try "current version". I'm using a GTX550 Nvidia card, and it's working fine with the current version driver.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04, it's known that there's sometimes poor performance on some NVIDIA cards. You could try installing the last **310** driver.

From **Jockey** (*Additional Drivers*), select the **nvidia-experimental-310** driver and install it. Alternatively, you can do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-experimental-310
```

on a Terminal. Theoretically this driver has a better performance, and [Dedoimedo](http://www.dedoimedo.com) said that the performance problems were solved with this driver. Don't be frightened because it's experimental, in my tests it doesn't have any problem.